# Verifying transaction before PDA account creation

Tags: transactions, pda, transaction-instructions

I want to create a PDA only if a user successfully transfers the funds.

If I create a client side transaction with a PDA creation as the final transaction, can the PDA creation continue to be made if the transfer of funds fail?

```
//Create transaction
const anchorTx = new Transaction();
let blockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized')).blockhash;
anchorTx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
anchorTx.feePayer = user.value;

anchorTx.add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
       fromPubkey: publicKey.value,
       toPubkey: itemPDA,
       lamports: Math.round(deposit * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL),
     })
);

//Fee
anchorTx.add(
  SystemProgram.transfer({
     fromPubkey: publicKey.value,
     toPubkey: treasury.value,
     lamports: fees.treasuryFeeLamports,
  })
);

let createPDATx = await program.value.methods.createItem(amount,item)
            .accounts({
                item: itemPDA,
                creator: user.value,
            }).instruction();

anchorTx.add(createPDATx);

signtransaction ... etc..
```

Basically I want to guarantee that the `createItem` method is not called if the transfer of funds do not complete. Is the order in which transactions listed matter?

Comment: Do you have control of the program where createItem is implemented? If so you could add the transfer into the createItem instruction with a CPI to the System program.

Comment: Ok, so I would create the PDA first with init/seed, and then have the transfer funds code within the createItem function? Would this prevent PDA being created if the transfer of funds is not completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Solana transactions are atomic in nature, the transaction you posted will fail if the transfer instruction doesn't go through. But this isn't stopping anyone to create their own transaction and directly call the `createItem` instruction without transferring SOL. Enforcing the payment on the client side won't help. You must include the transfer instruction within the program logic.

Here's how you make a CPI call to the `System Program` from within the program to transfer SOL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528742/how-to-transfer-sol-in-anchor-smart-contract-instruction.

You can always create a new question if you face any difficulty in implementing the CPI call.

Comment: If I move the transactions into the program logic so there is only one single client side transaction (which would be calling createItem), when someone signs the transaction with their wallet, will it show to the user all the inner funds transaction details like it does a normal client side transaction? Like x sol will be going here, x sol will be going here. etc..?

Comment: Yes, all the popular wallets currently are capable of simulating the SOL transfer correctly. They will accurately show the SOL deduction in the pop-up before the user signs the transaction.